# Read response of 400 Bad Request in catch()

Tags: angular, typescript

How to read bad request(400) response using .toPromise().catch()

Here is my code:

```
testConnection() {
    this.http.get(
      this.backendBaseUrl + `api/Test`, {observe: 'response'}
    ).toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      alert(`successfully.`);
    })
    .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
      alert(`connection not successful:\n${error}`); // error.error, error.message => undefined
    });
  }
```

it only alerts as Bad Request

**Headers:**

[image]

**Preview/ Response**

[image]

**Alert**

[image]

Update: I want to alert the response from Preview/Response not just Bad Request

**Solved: Found the issue, was having a HttpInterceptor which was removing the error message**

Comment: Can you check `error.status`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I found the problem, I was having an HttpInterceptor which was filtering out the error message. Thanks.